# MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener not called

Tags: java, android

I am stuck at a problem, where the `onPrepared()`-method is not being called, after `MediaPlayer.prepareAsync()`. Strangely, it does work the first time around, only after reinstantiating of the MediaPlayer it fails. Here is my "stripped down" code:

```
public void loadVideoStream(String videoUrl, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener opl, Context ctx) {
    try {
        this.stop(); //player.stop,reset,release,=null

        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onError: "+what + " " + extra);
                return false;
            }
        });
        player.setOnPreparedListener(opl);
        player.setDataSource(ctx, Uri.parse(videoUrl));

        if (this.surface != null) {
            player.setSurface(this.surface);
            player.prepareAsync();
            this.surface = null;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Everything seems to go well, the MediaPlayer does not throw any errors/warnings, but does not call the onPrepared-Statement (where the video is supposed to be started and some UI work to be done). I also made sure, that the surface is already created before calling `prepareAsync()`, but with no success. The file-format should be fine as well, since it works fine, if I use it the first time around.

Any tips/ideas appreciated!

Comment: By reinstantiating, do you mean you're calling `loadVideoStream()` again?

Comment: yes. player is released and set to null...